# I created the User class from flask-sqlalchemy. When I tried to run the application, I got an error

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

Here is the code:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)
```

and the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "d:/Python/python projects/Flask_Blog/run.py", line 1, in <module>
        from flaskblog import app
      File "d:\Python\python projects\Flask_Blog\flaskblog\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
        from flaskblog import routes
      File "d:\Python\python projects\Flask_Blog\flaskblog\routes.py", line 4, in <module>
        from flaskblog.models import User, Post
      File "d:\Python\python projects\Flask_Blog\flaskblog\models.py", line 6, in <module>
        class User(db.Model):
      File "d:\Python\python projects\Flask_Blog\flaskblog\models.py", line 8, in user
        username = db.column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    **TypeError: column() got an unexpected keyword argument 'unique'**
```

Comment: Why are there `**` before and after `unique=True`?

Comment: I wanted to locate unique easily by double asterisk

Comment: So, you put them to point out the `unique` argument. But, they are NOT used in the code .. right?

Comment: yes youu are right

Comment: I think you should be using `db.Column(...)`, i.e., with a capital C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in your code. You should use `db.Column` with uppercase `C` instead of `db.column`. So, your code should be like that:

```
username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)
```